# Why has this Java application crashed on CVDisplayLink thread on Mac?

Tags: java, macos, dump

Could anybody give me any clues about this why this java application has crashed, Im unable to replicate the issue but it says it crashed on CVDisplayLink thread on Mac, is this known problem ?

Process:         SongKong [12527]
Path:            /Applications/SongKong.app/Contents/MacOS/SongKong
Identifier:      com.jthink.songkong
Version:         3.0 (1.0)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [521]
Responsible:     SongKong [12527]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-09-12 14:35:00.730 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.4 (13E28)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  27FE9D66-7F0A-3CC3-A589-A56FE55FB4DD

Crashed Thread:  22  CVDisplayLink

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
Graphics hardware encountered an error and was reset: 0x00000000

Thread 0:: AppKit Thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c0fea1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c0fdd18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bf0ef15 **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bf0e539 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bf0de75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff92583a0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff925837b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff925835bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8c77524e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8c77489b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
10  libosxapp.dylib                 0x0000000127cbe42a -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 124
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8c76899c -[NSApplication run] + 553
12  libosxapp.dylib                 0x0000000127cbe23e +[NSApplicationAWT runAWTLoopWithApp:] + 156
13  libawt_lwawt.dylib              0x0000000127e9794f -[AWTStarter starter:] + 905
14  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff88be713e __NSThreadPerformPerform + 229
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bf1d5b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bf0ec62 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bf0e3ef __CFRunLoopRun + 831
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bf0de75 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
19  libjli.dylib                    0x000000010183cb34 CreateExecutionEnvironment + 871
20  libjli.dylib                    0x0000000101838ac4 JLI_Launch + 1952
21  com.jthink.songkong             0x00000001017cf8ab launch + 5243
22  com.jthink.songkong             0x00000001017ce2e6 main + 102
23  com.jthink.songkong             0x00000001017ce274 start + 52

...............
...............

Thread 22 Crashed:: CVDisplayLink
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c102866 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8d8e035c pthread_kill + 92
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff874c2b1a abort + 125
3   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib      0x00007fff8782d1ca gpusKillClient + 111
4   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib      0x00007fff8782e65f gpusSubmitDataBuffers + 484
5   com.apple.AMDRadeonX3000GLDriver    0x00001234801fc152 0x123480000000 + 2081106
6   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib      0x00007fff8782f1b2 gpuiFinishFence + 62
7   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib      0x00007fff878328f0 gldFinishObject + 48
8   GLEngine                        0x00007fff90265247 gleFinishFence + 94
9   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff889816a1 view_state_finish(_CAViewState*) + 54
10  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff8898042d view_draw(_CAView*, double, CVTimeStamp const*, bool) + 1397
11  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff8897fe7f view_display_link(double, CVTimeStamp const*, void*) + 150
12  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff8897fd40 link_callback + 237
13  com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8d8e85cc CVDisplayLink::performIO(CVTimeStamp*) + 206
14  com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8d8e7a08 CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 608
15  com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff8d8e778f startIOThread(void*) + 147
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8d8df899 _pthread_body + 138
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8d8df72a _pthread_start + 137
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8d8e3fc9 thread_start + 13

Comment: because "Graphics hardware encountered an error and was reset: 0x00000000" You might want to contact Apple about that, this looks like an hardware or OS issue.

Comment: thx, since found out he is running with a Virtual machine *using VMWare Fusion* so I suspect this is the underlying issue, no longer a problem I need to worry about.